# How to make a button within a listView work when clicked?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am basically creating a shopping cart application and my listView is being populated from my existing database and it gives you the store, brand, price, description, and image of the item and each image's information is stored in the database and put into an Item class that I created. So when for each item that's displayed in the listView, it also shows the add to cart button at the bottom of each image so that I can click that and add it to a shopping cart which will be another activity. Basically when I click this button, I want to run a query which will add that item to my database and then I will query all those added items for the shopping cart activity so that I can display all my items add to the cart there. So when I click on the button, how can I get that specific item and perform the query? How will it get that item? I've posted my code files below, any help would be great.

**shirtsActivity.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class shirtsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shirts);

        final SearchView shirtViewShirts = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView3);
        final DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
        final ListView listView;
        final ListAdapter shirtsAdapter;

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShirts);
        //List<Item> shirtsList = dbhelper.getAllShirts();
        ArrayList<Item> shirtsList = dbhelper.getAllShirts();

        if (shirtsList != null) {
            //shirtsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, shirtsList);
            shirtsAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), shirtsList);
            listView.setAdapter(shirtsAdapter);
        }

        shirtViewShirts.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                //query = query.toLowerCase();
                //query = Character.toString(query.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+query.substring(1);

                ListAdapter searchedShirtsAdapter;
                Log.e("Brand: ", query);
                ArrayList<Item> searchedShirtsList = dbhelper.getAllSearchedShirts(query);

                if (searchedShirtsList != null) {
                    searchedShirtsAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), searchedShirtsList);
                    listView.setAdapter(searchedShirtsAdapter);
                }

                listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_shirts_message));

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }

        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Item.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

public class Item {

    private String brand;
    private String size;
    private String price;
    private String store;
    private String description;
    private String ID;
    private String gender;

    public Item() {

    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getGender() {return gender; }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {return description; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (this.brand + "  " + this.store + "  " + this.price + "  " + this.description);
    }

}
```

**listItemAdapter.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public final class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> shirtItems) {
        super(context, 0, shirtItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        Item item = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout_shirts, parent, false);
        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView brand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_brand);
        TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_price);
        TextView store = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_store);
        TextView size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_size);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_description);
        ImageView shirtsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_shirts);
        Button addToCartButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addToCartButton);

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        brand.setText("Brand:" + "  " + item.getBrand());
        price.setText("Price:" + "  $" + item.getPrice());
        store.setText("Store:" + "  " + item.getStore());
        size.setText("Size:" + "  " + item.getSize());
        description.setText("Description:" + "  " + item.getDescription());

        Context context = parent.getContext();

        try {
            String itemName = item.getID();
            itemName = itemName.toLowerCase();
            String uri1 = "@drawable/"+itemName;
            int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            shirtsImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shirts); // Default image
            shirtsImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }

        addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //to get a specific item
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your item has been added to the cart!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**activity_shirts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#29A9D2"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/shirt">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView3"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:queryHint="Search for specific brand" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewShirts"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_shirts_message"
            android:text="No Results Found"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item_layout_shirts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addToCartButton"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/addToCartButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_store" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add item to Cart"
            android:id="@+id/addToCartButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_shirts"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addToCartButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_shirt_size"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shirts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addToCartButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view_shirts"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use last function from hirtsActivity.java file:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

You can choose specific item thanks for id parameter.

Comment: If I do that, then wouldn't the button click not work? Then it would only work if I click on the listView in that item? So then maybe I can just add some text to the list view for each item, make it look like a button and then use what you said?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully what you want get. You can use your button by start new intent, after your toast here:
addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //to get a specific item
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your item has been added to the cart!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
and you can get specific item by add extras to intent e. g. item.getBrand(), item.getPrize() etc

Comment: Let me explain my problem again. So actually I don't want to start a new activity when I click the button. Ok, so in my listView, it displays each clothing item and shows its price, brand, size, description, and image and for each item, I also have the add to cart button. So when I click on the add to cart button, I want to get that item's brand, price, store, description, etc. and run a query where I will store that item into an existing database that I have. So when I click on that button for a specific item, how do I get that specific item and its information?

Comment: Ok, now I understand, but I want to ask one qustion: Did the toast (Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your item has been added to the cart!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();) is showing after click that button?

Comment: Yes, it shows the toast after clicking the button, but I think I figured out my problem, so I just got the position of that item for which I clicked the button and then performed the insert query, but thanks for helping out.